# How to handle dynamic routes with HashRouter in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm working with a hashrouter and I want to support dynamic path (ie: `/user/:id`).

The way I've done it is :

```
<HashRouter>
    <Routes>
        <Route index element={<App />} />
        <Route path="/user/:id" component={User}/>
    </Routes>
</HashRouter>
```

I also tried working with `render`:

```
<Route path="/user/:id" render={(props) => <User {...props} />}/>
```

But nothing seem to work.

What is the proper way to do this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd still use the `element` prop. All `Route` components render their routed content on the `element` prop as JSX, i.e. a `ReactElement`.

```
<Route path="/user/:id" element={<User />} />
```

I'm guessing your next question might be, "How to access the `id` route match param?"

For this use the `useParams` hook in the `User` component.

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

...

const { id } = useParams();
```

If `User` is a class component and can't use React hooks, then create a wrapper component that can and pass the params in as a prop.

```
const UserWrapper = () => {
  const match = useMatch(); // i.e. match.params

  return <User match={match} /> // i.e. this.props.match.params
}

...

<Route path="/user/:id" element={<UserWrapper />} />
```

Comment: Thanks for you're answer, works like a charm. I just had to use `useParams` instead of `useMatch` in the wrapper. Could you explain the difference?

Comment: @Que20 No worries. `useMatch` returns the *entire* `match` object (*where `params` object is a property*) where as `useParams` returns *just* the `params` object. I did this in case the class component was "used" to the v5 APIs. `useParams` and passing `id` directly could also work. Sorry if this caused any confusion.